# Onclick passes value from JavaScript to jsf hibben form

Tags: javascript, forms, jsf, jsf-2

How to pass JavaScript  value "165432" to the JSF inputHidden tag in the form which after rendering the form will be ex: myForm:j_idt96:0:type.

By clicking the Submit button the onClick events triggers the javasctipt functionOne.

I want to pass "165432" to the inputHidden and then get that value in the Java Bean.

```
function functionOne(){
        ......   
document.getElementById("myForm:j_idt96:0:type").value ="165432";
}



<h:form id="myForm">
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
<h:inputHidden  id="type"   value="#{item.type}"  /> 
</ui:repeat>        
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit_complete}"      onclick="functionOne();"> 
<a4j:ajax execute="@form" render="pnlResult" />
</h:commandButton>  
</h:form>
```

Comment: There are not any errors in Bean when I use the folowing codes : Map<String,String> params=sFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
  String type=params.get("myForm:j_idt96:0:type");

Comment: I am using a4j:ajax because of onevent handling which the f:ajax does not have that option. how to autogenerated ID in javascript? the submit form works fine I can get all parameters.